# Как писать без полосок в html?

Tags: html, css

Всем привет! Я хотел создать сайт вроде Википедия но у меня возникло проблема с полоской. Когда я пишу `<a>sometext</a>` снизу появляется полоска которой я не знаю как бороться.

```css
body{
    background-color: black;
}
a.anum1{
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    font: icon;
    /* Вот здесь надо что-то писать */
}
```

```html
<div>
    <a href="ooops.html" class="anum1">menu</a>
    <a href="ooops.html" class="anum1">something</a>
    <a href="ooops.html" class="anum1">some...</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Какая полоска? Вы про стандартное подчёркивание ссылок? https://webref.ru/css/text-decoration

Comment: Боже, храни к̶о̶р̶о̶л̶е̶в̶у̶ интернеты...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`text-decoration` делает это подчеркивание.

```css
body{
    background-color: black;
}
a.anum1{
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    font: icon;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <a href="ooops.html" class="anum1">menu</a>
    <a href="ooops.html" class="anum1">something</a>
    <a href="ooops.html" class="anum1">some...</a>
</div>
```